# reflecting array inside interface

Tags: go, reflection

I'm trying to access via reflection an array within an interface.

Among other fields, I also have an array of strings:

```
type Configuration struct {
    ...
    SysVars []string
}
```

I can access the field *SysVars* like this:

```
elem := reflect.ValueOf(conf).Elem()
sysVarsInterface := elem.FieldByName("SysVars").Interface()
```

By this point, when using the GoLand's debugger I can see that *sysVarsInterface* is an interface with the two values I'm expecting. Since it's an array, I assume I need to treat it as interface and reflect it again? so it looks like this:

```
sysVarsValue := reflect.ValueOf(&sysVarsInterface)
sysVarsElem := sysVarsValue.Elem()
```

but iterating over it fails:

```
for i:=0; i< sysVarsElem.NumField(); i++ {
    vname := sysVarsElem.Type().Field(i).Name
    fmt.Println(vname)
}
```

saying:

```
panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.NumField on interface Value
```

any ideas what am I doing wrong? 
 I was using [this](http://www.golangprograms.com/how-to-get-struct-variable-information-using-reflect-package.html) as a reference

Comment: If you know the exact type of the slice field you can use `slice := elem.FieldByName("SysVars").Interface().([]string)`, ie type assertion. The just loop over the `slice` with plain for/range loop, no need to reflect anymore.

Comment: If you know that it's only a slice but you don't know the type of it's elements, then use reflect `sysVarsValue := elem.FieldByName("SysVars")` (no need to call Interface()). And then to loop over that do `for i := 0; i < sysVarsValue.Len(); i++ { ...` and then to index the slice inside the loop use `sysVarsValue.Index(i)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to double reflection , you can iterate SysVars like this :

```
p := &Configuration{
SysVars :[]string{"a","b","c"},
}

s:= reflect.ValueOf(p).Elem().FieldByName("SysVars")
for i:=0 ; i< s.Len() ; i++ {
   fmt.Println(s.Index(i).String())
}
```

Comment: perfetct! also, if this doesn't exceed the scope of the post, would you mind explain why my solution was not correct, and yours is?

Comment: @yoadw An interface holds two pair, a value and a type when you start reflection on a variable you are extracting underneath data from an interface no need to assert to interface again. It's like you parse an string to int then convert int to string again. You can learn lot about reflection in this page , laws of reflection : https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection